# Does Topic messaging work with chrome extensions?

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, push-notification

I am trying to implement Chrome Extension that receives push messages from Firebase.I have tried referring firebase docs but I cannot find any info regarding this.Is it possible to implement the same? Any reference document link is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the fact that firebase is real time and gives you update on all updates in its database might help you. you can refer this link here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/